Angle stop nut and ferrule stuck in the ferrule remover tool
I just received this ferrule remover tool. The first half of the process worked great: the ferrule [and nut] came right out.

But the nut is really really locked on the thread of the removal tool. I've put enough force on trying to get it off that it has lightly scratched the other end. I'm uncertain if the thread were still whole.
Any hints on how that nut/ferrule can be disengaged from the disengagement tool? (I have three other lines to remove tonight if possible ;)

Break this up into question and answer.  You can answer your own questions.

Glad you’re making progress. A lot of people leave the old nut and ferrule on and re-use it. You can also gently nick the ferrule with a hacksaw blade (don’t touch the house copper!) and then break the ferrule by twisting a slot screwdriver in the new slot.

@AloysiusDefenestrate. Nice tip.  In these cases none of these lines afforded direct access to the ferrule. They are hidden by the nuts that  could not be moved away from the ferrule.   These are decades old, maybe 45+ years.

Oh look at this.  I might have simply purchased the wrong tool (metric instead of SAE). Thus the threading issue..

Another update I did get the nut and ferrule off by bringing in the heavy guns: shop vice and heavy wrenches.  The top two threads are kinda toast. Let's see if it can serve for another three intakes. Otherwise (and in any case) another brand is arriving tomorrow.
No dice. Ferrule remover has checked out.
Yet another update. The "other brand" ferrule puller arrived a bit ago and "we" gave it a go. Notice it has thicker lever arm. Actually all three advantages shown in the image were needed: the Kroil lubricant, vice grips, and even with the thicker lever arm it barely held (and actually got bent as can be seen. But those seventies vintage ferrules are now coming out!

